# OpenCV Python Assertion failed error when playing .avi

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am just beginning to learn OpenCV and am working through the tutorials here: https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

This is the code I've written to play the sample video.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('samples/vtest.avi')

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the error message I get:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/opencv-20161020-7399-1yrk4nm/opencv-2.4.13.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3739
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vidFile_tutorial.py", line 14, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv-20161020-7399-1yrk4nm/opencv-2.4.13.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I'm unsure that the problem is an assertion fail error since I've chosen the file as specified by the tutorial. Moreover, when I attempt to play vtest.avi manually I encounter a codec error with QuickTime. Therefore, I suspect it's video codec issues with OpenCV. But I'm unsure if the diagnosis is correct and how I would go about fixing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the same issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31299501/5008845). Can you print the shape of `frame`? You'll probably find out that it's already grayscale and you don't need to convert.

Comment: `print frame.shape` returns with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'` So i guess the image isn't being read properly in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
So I've managed to resolve the issue by using OpenCV 3.1.0 rather than 2.4.13.1.

With OpenCV 3.1.0 everything works fine.