# Python (simple application to save images using opencv)

Tags: python, opencv

I get this error after adding the part for saving the images, any idea how to get this error fixed ?
 [This answer it doesn't help and it is in c++](http://OpenCV%20Error:%20Assertion%20failed%20(scn%20==%203%20%7C%7C%20scn%20==%204)%20in%20cv::%20cvtColor,%20file%20..%5C..%5C..%5C..%5Copencv%5Cmodules%5Cimgproc%5Csrc%5Ccolor.cpp,%20line%203737)

```
for co in range(1, 5):
fsize = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (100, 100))
```

...........................................................................

```
errorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-86e0bb6aa30e> in <module>()
     62 
     63 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 64     create()

<ipython-input-1-86e0bb6aa30e> in create()
     21                 ret, frame = camera.read()
     22 
---> 23                 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     24 
     25         faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(

error: C:\build\2_4_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv:: cvtColor, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297841/opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4-in-cv-cvtcolor-file)

Comment: No its not the answer you refereed to is in c++

Answer (score 1):

As |'L'| has said, it may be the same issue where your camera capture a gray scale image so the conversion does not work.
Another possibility is youy indicate a wrong camera. The front camera for a mac is camercapture(1) while 0 for window, try change this.

Comment: "The front camera for a mac is camercapture(1) while 0 for window" --- This is not true. If you only have a single camera, it should be `VideoCapture(0)` regardless of the OS. I have a Macbook and my front camera is still `0`. Also, the paths displayed hint at the OP using Windows anyways.

Comment: No it doesnot work for me, and the error came after i changed while (True): into for co in range(1, 5): and also this part fsize = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (100, 100))
   cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.JPEG' % (path,count), fsize)